# ggvis doesn't render interactive plots with rstudio server

Tags: r, ggvis

Love the idea of ggvis as using shiny and ggplot a lot at the moment. But ggvis is not rendering interactive plots in RStudio-server.

- RStudio server version 0.98.953 running on ubuntu.
- R 3.0.2
- Shiny-server 1.2.0.359 also running on same server.
- ggvis 0.3.0.1
- shiny 0.10.0
- Firefox 30.0 OR chrome 35.0.1916.153 m

This renders as expected:

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points()
```

When trying to render the following, "viewer" window flashes but nothing appears. Message appears as expected:

```
Showing dynamic visualisation. Press Escape/Ctrl + C to stop

mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_smooths(span = input_slider(0.5, 1, value = 1)) %>%
  layer_points(size := input_slider(100, 1000, value = 100))
```

ggvis plots on http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ etc. render as expected.

Firefox or chrome both same. Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue on R 3.1.0 Patched; I'm on Win7 / RStudio desktop however. Do you have an option to upgrade R? Might worth a try.